# Are the new gTLDs considered less stable?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, top-level-domains

I'm looking at creating some links using a `.link` gTLD but I'm unsure about whether I can trust new gTLDs for pages that I need to last 2-4 years minimum. As of the start of 2015, how stable are the new gTLDs and should this be a concern?

For example, `.link` is managed by a company called [Uniregistry](https://uniregistry.com/). Does the stability of this startup company relate to the stability of my website hosted on a `.link` gTLD? Are the new gTLD's considered any less stable?

Comment: As long as its accredited by ICAN you have little to worry about.

Comment: Note that there is a question of country code TLD's and conflicting with local intersts (see .ly TLD: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ly where the domain was seized allegedly for conflicting with sharia). What happens if Uniregistry goes out of business?

Comment: @Steve See my answer here about that: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/76747/my-domain-registrar-has-gone-bankrupt-but-the-domain-is-locked-what-can-i-do

Answer (score 2):

The new TLDs are as secure as the legacy TLDs. Here why?

1. For starters, every new domain registry operator had to pass a rigorous application process to own the rights to a new TLD (Financial, Policies, Technical etc.)
2. If a new TLD operator did fail ICANN, the governing body for the Internet and all domains has backup processes in place where they would pass the TLD rights of a failed operator to another stable registry. This is built into ICANNs governing policies. This focus is on making the Internet a better experience for the end-user.
3. Essentially, once a new TLD has been launched and a domain is registered it will be supported for its lifetime.

Comment: What is the lifetime of a TLD?

Answer (score 0):

It really goes to who the owner is and how stable the company is. Since gTLDs are so expensive and requires a huge infrastructure build-out, generally, this would not be a fly-by-night organization, however, it can also be a case where huge financial risks are taken where the business plan/model is weak but the risk is taken for potentially high rewards. You would have to do your own research on a case by case basis and ask yourself this, "How comfortable do I feel with this company?" Trust your instincts. gTLDs purchases are on a year by year basis and will require a commitment of several years before a gTLD will really begin to pay-off. If you cannot see this level of commitment from a company, then you too run a risk. Life is all about risk, risk assessment, and risk avoidance/abatement. Learn to do this well and you will have a good life.