# Domain Renewal - Unable to contact current registrar

Tags: domain-registration, domain-registrar

I have a domain name which was registered with a registrar called enameco.  It is due for renewal soon.  Apparently the original registrar - enameco -  do not exist anymore - atleast the original site is no more in action

When I do a WhoIS on my domain, here is what I get - (xxx are replaced with some private info). Specifically, it says that my current registrar is Endurance

```
Registry Domain ID: XXXXXX_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN
Registrar WHOIS Server: 
Registrar URL: 
Updated Date: XXXX
Creation Date: xxx
Registrar Registration Expiration Date: XXX
Registrar: ENDURANCE
Registrar IANA ID: 

Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited https://www.icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
```

I dont have any information on current registrar Endurance - web/login - or anyway to renew my domain.

Any idea how to go about and renew the domain in this case

Comment: See also [My domain registrar has gone bankrupt but the domain is locked, what can I do?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/76747/my-domain-registrar-has-gone-bankrupt-but-the-domain-is-locked-what-can-i-do)

Answer (score 7):

I resolved the issue. It appears that Endurance owns multiple reseller registrars under them - and dint know which one to contact.

I tried the my luck with few of their reseller site's support (all the sites look the same - which was comforting) but dint have much luck.

Eventually figured that "dotster" is my new registrar.  A [tweet](https://mobile.twitter.com/24AheadDotCom_/status/1029555341950889985) in the past  helped us to guess above.

I guess probably WHOIS should also include the cPanel url :)

Answer (score 4):

I would have thought that enameco is a reseller and that the upstream registrar is really ENDURANCE. But it looks like [they are Icann accredited](https://www.icann.org/registrar-reports/accreditation-qualified-list.html). There is no mention of that registrar being terminated or in breach of registrar agreement. So either a 'bulk transfer' was done very recently for some reason, or something slipped your attention.

Contact ENDURANCE since they are listed and your current registrar and they may be able to help you.